# To handle special characters in SQL server database, which should be used varchar or nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, text, varchar, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

I am asking a simple question that, to handle special  characters in my Mobile/Tablet web app, which data types should I use?

1. Varchar
2. NVarchar
3. Text
4. NText

EDIT:

IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead. [More Detail Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Should we use nVarchar  as I read somewhere that some devices, such as mobile phones, still cannot correctly handle Unicode data.

Please give your expert suggestions?

Comment: Read the documentation and make a decision. We are not here to read the documentation for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 or 2 depending on the "special characters" you'll be saving. Just depends on how "special" they are.

I will say though, definitely not Text as it's deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017